# Resample data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my initial `data.head()` has result:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 45993 entries, 2009-11-17 14:14:00 to 2012-12-16 14:26:00
Data columns (total 4 columns):
rain         45993  non-null values
temp         45993  non-null values
windspeed    45993  non-null values
dew_point    45993  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4)

2009-11-17 14:14:00  0   22.5    4.9     12.3
2009-11-17 14:44:00  0   22.3    6.1     12.1
2009-11-17 15:14:00  0   22.1    5.3     12.5
2009-11-17 15:44:00  0   22.2    3.3     12.0
2009-11-17 16:14:00  0   20.4    4.9     11.7
```

When i resample:

```
data = data.resample('30min', how ='sum')
data.head()
```

i get :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 68861 entries, 2009-01-12 00:00:00 to 2012-12-16 14:00:00
Freq: 30T
Data columns (total 4 columns):
rain         45987  non-null values
temp         45987  non-null values
windspeed    45987  non-null values
dew_point    45987  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4)

2009-01-12 00:00:002     0   17.4    7.1     14.6
2009-01-12 00:30:00  0   17.4    7.2     14.7
2009-01-12 01:00:00  0   18.0    10.5    14.3
2009-01-12 01:30:00  0   18.3    9.6     14.2
2009-01-12 02:00:00  0   18.4    10.8    14.8
```

As you see my initial date is 2009-11-17 14:14:00 but resample day start at 2009-01-12. Can anyone explain that happens?

**EDIT , i did find the problem** , so for others 
the provided dataset had :

```
2009-01-12 00:00:00 value
2009-01-12 00:30:00 value ... but the next line was!!!!!
2009-01-12 01:00    value
```

so the missing :00 seconds made all the confusion

Comment: pls post ``df.info()``

Comment: i just edited my initial post

Comment: very strange, you have more elements in result dataset than in initial dataset, may be your data converted from low frequency to high?

Comment: what you mean low to high? my dataset is just 30min interval records and with resample i just want to make more readable my data (14:14 --> 14:00 , 14:44 --> 14:30)